# Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I get the following exception with the xmal code and c# code provided . Please help.

**Exception:** Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.IConvertible'

**XAML Code:**

```
    <Grid x:Name="cheque1" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{DynamicResource Cheque1Position}" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
        <Grid.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ChequeVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="0" diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="None">
                <Binding Path="_ItemDASFlowExtensions.DepositSummary.ScannedCheques"/>
                <Binding Path="_Common.DynamicIndex" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Grid.Visibility>
        <Image x:Name="ChequeToBeReturned1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Style="{DynamicResource ReturnCheque}" Margin="0,5,5,0">
            <Image.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ChequeVisibilityConverter}" ConverterParameter="0, Validity" diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High">
                    <Binding Path="_ItemDASFlowExtensions.DepositSummary.ScannedCheques"/>
                    <Binding Path="_Common.DynamicIndex" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Image.Visibility>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

### C# Converter Code:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{   
    Visibility visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    IList<IChequeMediaItem> array = values[0] as IList<IChequeMediaItem>;
    int dynIndex =-1 ;
    if (values[1]!=null)
    {               
        dynIndex = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
    } 
}
```

I get InvalidCastException at the statement

```
dynIndex = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
```

Comment: Can you `Debug.Write` or Add watch over `values[1]` and check if it has the right value you are trying to convert

Comment: Getting  {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue} value in Values[1].

Answer (score 2):

`_Common.DynamicIndex` is not properly set or the binding is wrong. In your converter, its returning [DependencyProperty.UnsetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) which is the equivalent of null.

The converter class is fine, check your binding is done properly and check if the value is not null at runtime.